# Screen Capture and Sharing in Android 5.0

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, screensharing

There is a mention about Screen capture and Sharing api in Android 5.0 at:
[Android 5.0 APIs](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html)

There its mentioned about **MediaProjectionDemo** class in the **ApiDemos**.
I could not find it anywhere to download. Where can I find it?
Are they yet to publish API demos for Android 5.0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the source code [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/bf1e262/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/media/projection/MediaProjectionDemo.java):

Comment: how can one simply save this recording in a .mp4 file using this code, do u have any idea?

Comment: @KunalK : i also need the same thing. Have you got any help about this?

Comment: Nope not yet. Working on some other things so didnt get chance.

Comment: in the thread  https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=77791
on #6 point 3 he has mentioned how to go about it. but i didn't get it.

Comment: Hi people, did you figure out how to save the file? It would be of great help!

Answer (score 4):

I have just downloaded the 5.0 SDK in my Eclipse Android Development environment.

Makesure that you have downloaded the complete SDK apart from some system Images which you dont require.

If you have downloaded the SDK, then create and emulator device with Android 5.0.

In that, go to Apps---> API Demos ---> Media ----> Media Projection.

I can able to see the Media Projections App.

Comment: I think he's asking for the _source code_ for that demo. I couldn't find it anywhere either. There's an open issue about this: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77791

Comment: If you don't want to download the project you can also access it here https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ScreenCapture

Answer (score 1):

I was going through the solutions available on web to take screenshot, So I found some really helpful which I would like to share here:

1) Here is the [MediaProjectionAPIDemo](https://github.com/mtsahakis/MediaProjectionDemo) available on github

2) Here is another [Project](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ScreenCapture) using MediaProjectionAPI available on github

3) Another [solution](https://github.com/openstf/minicap) which require NDK to stream real time Screen Capture

4) And at last, [here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/android-screenshot-library/wikis/UserGuide.wiki) is Android Screenshot library

Hope it will help you to take off :-)